# Nested Loops for all possible move permutations?

Tags: objective-c, loops, combinations, permutation

I am trying to figure out all possible moves that are possible to make in a game that I am playing.  Firstly I make a loop within a loop that stores all possible moves that can be made.

```
NSArray *enemyFeildCopy = @[@"ef0",@"ef1",@"ef2"];
NSArray *yourfeildCopy = @[@"f1",@"f2",@"f3"];
for (NSString *card in yourfeildCopy) {
    for (NSString *attackCard in enemyFeildCopy) {
        NSLog(@"%@ attack %@",card,attackCard);
        NSDictionary *dictonary = @{@"move":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ attack %@",card,attackCard],@"attackingCard":card};
        [allAttackOptions addObject:dictonary];
    }
}
```

And when I do run that code I get the following log output...

```
2015-05-11 00:10:04.562 clicks[56629:5396833] f1 attacks ef0
2015-05-11 00:10:04.562 clicks[56629:5396833] f1 attacks ef1
2015-05-11 00:10:04.562 clicks[56629:5396833] f1 attacks ef2
2015-05-11 00:10:04.562 clicks[56629:5396833] f2 attacks ef0
2015-05-11 00:10:04.563 clicks[56629:5396833] f2 attacks ef1
2015-05-11 00:10:04.563 clicks[56629:5396833] f2 attacks ef2
2015-05-11 00:10:04.563 clicks[56629:5396833] f3 attacks ef0
2015-05-11 00:10:04.563 clicks[56629:5396833] f3 attacks ef1
2015-05-11 00:10:04.563 clicks[56629:5396833] f3 attacks ef2
```

Now for the part I am stuck on, I want to have my code as efficient as possible and I want it to be able scale on increased/decrease enemy field targets or increase/decrease in your field positions. Here is the code.

```
for (NSDictionary *firstMove in allAttackOptions) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= pow(9, 3)/3; i++) {//amount of times firstMove will be the first move
        NSLog(@"%@",[firstMove valueForKey:@"move"]);
        for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++) {//ammount of moves you can do in 1 turn
            NSLog(@"%@",[[allAttackOptions objectAtIndex:(unknown equation)] valueForKey:@"move"]);
        }
         NSLog(@"---End Move---"); 
    }    
}
```

If I had this working properly the log on this I should be getting.

```
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:33.296 clicks[56755:5432421] ---End Move--- 
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef1
2015-05-11 00:49:33.296 clicks[56755:5432421] ---End Move--- 
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef2
2015-05-11 00:49:33.296 clicks[56755:5432421] ---End Move--- 
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef1
2015-05-11 00:49:27.689 clicks[56755:5432421] f1 attack ef0
2015-05-11 00:49:33.296 clicks[56755:5432421] ---End Move---
```

Personally I can not figure out what to fill in on grabbing the index for (unknown equation)  Thanks for your time!